# LINQ to XML select

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have two xml documents with some elements like

doc1

```
<Item id="22"/>
<Item id="33"/>
<Item id="44"/>
...
```

doc2

```
<Item id="33"/>
<Item id="44"/>
<Item id="66"/>
<Item id="88"/> 
...
```

I need a query to select 
only those elements from doc1 that are missing in doc2 ignoring other doc2 elements.

In this case the result will be:

```
<Item id="22"/>
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you create a List with all ids from the second list, and check for each item of doc1 if it is in the list.
Performance wise, I think it isnt the best choice - but it should work

```
        var qry = from item in doc1.Descendants("Item")
                  where
                     !(from item2 in doc2.Descendants("Item")
                     select item2.Attribute("id"),Value
                     ).ToList().Contains(item.Attribute("id").Value)
                  select item;
```

In the linq-statement above, I think the list of ids is created for every element in doc1. Better option would be to create the list first and then use the list in the next statement:

```
        List<string> items = (from item2 in doc2.Descendants("Item")
                              select item2.Attribute("id").Value
                             ).ToList();

        var qry = from item in doc1.Descendants("Item")
                  where !items.Contains(item.Attribute("id").Value)
                  select item;
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably something along the lines of

```
doc1.Where(i1=>doc2.All(i2 => i2.id != i1.id))
```

could get you there.

HOWEVER, this is performing a subquery on doc2 for each element in doc1. Make sure they are small!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the `ExceptedBy` method from the [MoreLinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) library. Assuming the `Item` elements are directly under the root element:

```
var doc1 = XDocument.Load("doc1.xml");
var doc2 = XDocument.Load("doc2.xml");

var doc1Elements = doc1.Root.Elements("Item");
var doc2Elements = doc2.Root.Elements("Item");

var diff = doc1Elements.ExceptBy(doc2Elements, e => e.Attribute("id").Value);
```